# Dynamics Portal Last Login of a Portal enabled Contact

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I'm developing a MS Dynamics portal and I have my test contact authenticating (using Azure AD) into the portal but I can't find how to get the last (or any) date time the contact logged into the portal.
The audit entity only seems to have that info for system users.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
For system users the audit entity stores logins.
For portal contacts you need to go to the site settings of the portal and set Authentication/LoginTrackingEnabled = true.
Then the field 'adx_identity_lastsuccessfullogin' is populated on the contact entity (table)